# How to Verify if each element the Array contains the search string in Typescript/protractor

Tags: arrays, typescript, search, substring

How do i Verify if each element of the Array contains the search string in Typescript/ Protractor??
All the console statements returned false as they were looking for complete text rather than a search string. Please suggest a solution.

```
arr = [ 'Citibank, N.A.', 'Citi China Companies', 'Citibank Ireland' ] 
search string = 'citi'

Then('I enter search text where the highlighted search results will include a Client Company Name {string}, {string}', async (searchText, companyName) => {
    await acctmgrclientselection.deleteSearchText().then(async () => {
        await acctmgrclientselection.getSelectClientSearchInputEl().sendKeys(searchText).then(async () => {
            await acctmgrclientselection.getSelectClientSearchInputEl().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).then(async () => {
            await dashboardFilter.getEmployeeListGrid().count().then( async ( CountVal ) => {
                if(CountVal >1)
                {
                var strArr: Array<string> = [];
                await acctmgrclientselection.getClientTblCompanyName().getText().then(async (text) => {
                    await strArr.push(text)
                    //strArr.forEach(function(value){
                var sortable = [];
                strArr.forEach(value => {
                sortable.push([value]);
                let sorted_array: Array<string> = sortable.map(arr => arr[0])
                let result = sorted_array.every(element => element.includes(searchText))
                console.log(result)    
                });
                });
                }
                else 
                {
           //clear criteria
            console.log('clear criteria');
                    await element(by.cssContainingText('mat-card.empty-results.mat-card p','0 results matching your criteria')).isDisplayed().then(async()=>{
                        await element(by.cssContainingText('mat-card.empty-results.mat-card a','Clear Criteria')).isDisplayed();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: `array.every(element => element.includes(searchString))`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array, https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String. You really need to learn the principle of await, because you're missing the point.

Comment: Yes, i have to look into await.

Comment: It still retrieves a false

Comment: Then it means that not all elements contain the substring. What is the array? What is the search string?

Comment: array is arr = [ 'Citibank, N.A.', 'Citi China Companies', 'Citibank Ireland' ] and search string is 'citi'

Comment: So, the result is correct. None of the strings in the array contains `citi`. They all contain `Citi`, but `citi` and `Citi` are two different strings.

Comment: It retrieves False even if the Search is Citi

Comment: No, it doesn't: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yutebg

Comment: ...Citi
[ [ 'Citibank, N.A.', 'Citi China Companies', 'Citibank Ireland' ] ]
[ [ 'Citibank, N.A.', 'Citi China Companies', 'Citibank Ireland' ] ]
false

Comment: It retrieves false. No clue why

Comment: I can explain why some code returns false, but not without seeing the code. Post a complete minimal code snippet. You can fork my stackblitz and type it there, and then post the link, for example. Or you can edit your question and post it there, too.

Comment: Works only when the search completely matches with the array

Comment: It does what you asked: *How do i Verify if **each** element of the Array contains the search string*. But please, read the docuentation of Array and String, that I linked to, to adapt the code to what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I have modified the code above. The same code retrieves true for you and false for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the regex with search string.

```
const pattern = new RegExp("Citi");
const result = sorted_array.every(element => pattern.test(element));
console.log(result);
```